# Remove everything not matched by regex

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I am trying to create a visualisation that removes non punctuation characters, but still keeps track of chapters in the string.

So far I achieved to create the following regex to match what I want to preserve:

`(\CAPÍTULO ([0-9]+))|([\\?.,:;!¡¿。、·*\(\)\[\]\-–\_«»\'\'\/@#$&\%\^=+\|<>\"])`

How can I do to replace the rest of the text from a string?

Comment: Can you give an example of inputs and outputs?

Comment: Are these specific punctuation characters you want to preserve, or do you want to preserve all non-alphanumerics? Do you want to preserve the position of the retained punctuation characters, replacing the non-punctuation characters with spaces, or squash the result?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the [`replace`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function, try this for an example:

```js
var str = "whatever, string, you like!";
var newStr = str.replace(/\w/g, ' ');

console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: That does not fulfill the requirements

Comment: @jsdario I updated the answer to match your requirement

Comment: This will remove `CAPITULO 1`, which he wants to keep.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var r = /(CAPÍTULO [0-9]+|[\\?.,:;!¡¿。、·*\(\)\[\]\-–\_«»\'\'\/@#$&\%\^=+\|<>\"])|(.)/g
var s = "ABC!@#123^&*XYZ;";
var p = s.replace(r, "$1");

// Result: "!@#^&*;"
```

First, it matches all characters in group 1, and any non-matches fall into the second group.  Since the result of a group number (i.e. $1) is empty if not found, this effectively clears everything except the first group matches.

If you need to preserve the placement of the other characters you could do this:

```
var r = /(CAPÍTULO [0-9]+|[\\?.,:;!¡¿。、·*\(\)\[\]\-–\_«»\'\'\/@#$&\%\^=+\|<>\"])|(.)/g
var s = "ABC!@#123^&*XYZ;";
s.replace(r, "$1,").split(",");

// Result: ["", "", "", "!", "@", "#", "", "", "", "^", "&", "*", "", "", "", ";", ""]
```

You just need to handle the extra `""` at the end. ;) This works because instead of replacing with nothing, (i.e. `"$1"` becomes `""` for non-matches), the comma (or any character you want really), keeps track of the positions. You could use anything, such as `s.replace(r, "$1~").split("~");` also.

Comment: This seems to remove the `CAPITULO 1` part which he wants to keep.

Comment: Try now - he had `\C` in the original post, and I left it in. ;)

Answer (score 0):

> removes non punctuation characters, but still keeps track of chapters in the string.

The classic way to do this is to match on the thing you **do** want to keep (`CAPITULO [0-9]+`), OR (`|`) other things you **don't** want to keep--in this case, non-punctuation characters (`\w`), and capture that, then replace the latter with an empty string.

```js
const regexp = /CAPITULO [0-9]+|(\w)/g;

const input = "CAPITULO 22 .#( nonpunctuation characters $%&*'";

const processed = input.replace(regexp, (match, match1) => match1 ? '' : match);

console.log(processed);
```

If you really want to list out all the punctuation characters to preserve, then replace `\w` in the above with

```
[^\\?.,:;!¡¿。、·*()[\]\-–_«»'\/@#$&\%\^=+\|<>\"]
```

If you want to preserve the placement of the remaining characters, then change the replacement function to

```
(match, match1) => match1 ? ' ' : match
```

Comment: He has a specific regex of characters to preserve. Also, he wants to preserve the character locations, not just remove them.